# Is there an impact on cache misses when transposing a matrix if the starting address doesn't match the cache block's beginning?

Tags: c, caching

Hi so I am learning about caches in school and had a quick question. Essentially, I am trying to find the optimal way to transpose a matrix such that its misses are under a certain value x. One of the questions, I had was that if the starting address of my matrix I want to transpose does not map to the beginning of the cache block then would the number of misses increase compared to if it had pointed to the beginning of the cache block? My thinking is that it would increase the number of misses because once you reach the end of the cache then when you go back to the starting address it would go to some random point in the cache rather than the beginning. I don't know if my thinking is correct or if my reasoning is sound. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Some things that I did to solve this problem were to try to draw it on paper.

Comment: There are a number of different types of cahce systems. You need to provide information about the cache system used.

Comment: it's a L1 cache system

Comment: Such micro-optimisation is probably a waste of time anyway. You're probably better off doing a blocky transpose where a whole block is small enough to easily fit in your lowest cache. As matrix transpose is O(n^2), you're other matrix operations will probably be slower at O(n^3) etc. so in practice, optimising the transpose operation might not be worth doing in place of simple code.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix transposition is notorious for bad performance caused largely by the fact that traversing rows of an array stored in row-major order causes numerous cache set conflicts that cause evictions and reloads of cache lines. This is often the dominant effect and should be avoid by a technique of organizing the matrix into small blocks (a few rows and a few columns) that are copied from the source to the destination (if different) or swapped (if the transpose is in-place, typically with a square matrix). The idea is that a block should be small enough that all of its elements can be held in cache at the same time, while being as large as possible to accomplish that without causing many other cache evictions.

It is possible that the starting alignment of the array and the length of the rows of the array may cause some issues in handling the transposition. Sometimes these can be avoided or mitigated, as by handling a few poorly aligned elements along the edges of the array while handling the bulk of the array using well-aligned blocks.

Comment: So just to clarify because the starting address is not aligned with the beginning of the cache line, there will be more misses.